# json.dumps in python over a list of user-defined objects

Tags: python, django, json

I have a class called photo.  This class has 4 fields, one of while is called file. This file is of Django's image field type.

I have a list composed of these image fields.  I want to convert this python list in to a json string. If I call `json.dumps(listData)` on my list, then I get this error:

```
ImageFieldFile: photos/KObtu.jpg.
```

This seems sensible.  The system represents the image field as a string that is not valid json. How can I override this output string?  Alternatively, Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom JSON Encoder class that knows how to encode ImageFieldFile:

```
import json
from django.db.models.fields.files import ImageFieldFile

class EnhancedJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """
    JSONEncoder subclass that knows how to encode Django "ImageFieldFile"s.
    """

    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, ImageFieldFile):
            # Treat ImageFieldFile as a unicode string
            return super(EnhancedJSONEncoder, self).default(unicode(o))
        else:

            return super(EnhancedJSONEncoder, self).default(o)
```

You would then call json.dumps() as:

```
json.dumps(listData, cls=EnhancedJSONEncoder))
```

This assumes you're wanting ImageFieldFile to be represented as a string